# How to Use Title() Filter Hook to Change Page Titles, but Not Menu Titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use a filter hook to add an image before titles of my pages, but it also adds them to my menu titles. How can I get around this?

```
function scissorTitle ($title) 
{

 $scissortitle .= "<img src='*image_link*'>" . $title;



  return $scissortitle;
}
add_filter( 'title', 'scissorTitle', 10);
```

Comment: fixing grammar and improving formatting to make the question more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The filter `title` has two parameters `$title` and `$id` you can use $id to change the only specific title of the page [Check docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/). Your full code should look like this:

```
function scissorTitle ($title, $id) {
    global $post;

    if (is_singular() && $post->ID == $id) {
        $title = '<img src="image_link">' . $title;
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title',  'scissorTitle', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you. The image is showing up in the nav, but only one image on the left instead of 2 on each side. It wasn't the end result I originally wanted, but looks cool, so I'll use it.